# How to see what object is going wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, memory-management, crash

I'm implementing a multivue application, and it was working just until i try to manage memory.

Here is the situation :

[image: Error]

When i load the new UIViewController (which was working), it gives me this error. I can't step over this error with the debugger, and so i couldn't know what object is making crash my app.

I try to put a :

```
Nslog(@"Checker");
```

to see where it stops, but no stop, all seems to work... Really strange situation.

So my question is, how could we know wich object is link with the fail address ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You are likely releasing memory that you shouldn't be (usually because it was never actually alloc'd, or you are releasing the same thing twice).

In order to debug this, turn on "Enable Zombie Objects". It can be found under the "Diagnostics" tab of your scheme. XCode will then show you when the bad call is made.

Comment: But when i've got somthing like "message sent to deallocated instance 0x75bc7e0", how could i know which 0x75bc7e0 refears to ?

Answer (score 0):

In LLVM compiler, address can be symbolicate using following

```
 (lldb) image lookup --address 0x75bc7e0
```

or

```
 (lldb) im loo -a 0x75bc7e0
```